i'm trying to make a small python program which can add/sub/mult/div two numbers
a = print("[1]ADD")
b = print("[2]Subtract")
c = print("[3]Multiply")
d = print("[4]Divide")

ip1 = int(input("Enter your choice :"))
x = int(input("enter 1st numer :"))
y = int(input("enter 2nd numer :"))
z1 = x + y
z2 = x - y
z3 = x * y
z4 = x / y

if ip1 == 1:
    opt1 =("addition of {} and {} is {}")
    print(opt1.format(x, y , z1))

elif ip1 == 2:
    opt1 = ("subtraction of {} and {} is {}")
    print(opt1.format(x, y, z2))

elif ip1 == 3:
    opt1 =("multiplication of {} and {} is {}")
    print(opt1.format(x, y, z3))

elif ip1 == 4:
    opt1 = ("division of {} and {} ia {}")
    print(opt1.format(x, y, z4))

else:
    print("invalid parameter")

ip1 = int(input("Enter your choice :"))

if input == 5 or more which I have defined invalid parameter but it doesn't print directly invalid parameter, it's take input x = int(input("enter 1st numer :")) and y = int(input("enter 2nd numer :")) then print invalid parameter.

You can check if the operator is 5 or larger before you ask for x & y.

So you need to take an action right after ip1 = int(input("Enter your choice :"))

If I understand it correctly, you want to end early if they input an option that wasn't offered. You need to first check if the input for ip1 was among values you will handle and only then continue execution.
First, these lines, this is most likely not what you want:
a = print("[1]ADD")
b = print("[2]Subtract")
c = print("[3]Multiply")
d = print("[4]Divide")

There is no use in creating variables. Simply use print("[1]ADD") instead.
And now for the program flow.
For instance (not so nice):
ip1 = int(input("Enter your choice :"))
if ip1 in (1,2,3,4):
    # rest of your code indented in
else:
    print("invalid parameter")

This kind of code writing easily becomes unreadable, though. Here you can see, why grouping things together makes your code more easily readable and allows for creation of more complex flows. Also, this kind of approach will allow you to have the user make a valid choice after making an invalid one, without restarting the program.
The logical order would be something like this:

Present the valid options.
Take the user choice
Check if the user choice is valid
3a. If not valid, present a message and let them choose again (and provide an Exit option possibly).
3b. If valid, ask for the 1st and 2nd number.
Make the calculation and present the result.

This can be done as similar as above - or in my opinion better - by creating a function (1), grouping valid values for ip1 in a dict and thereby mapping it to the underlying functions  and strings (2) or by creating a class (3), in no order of validity or correctness for this relatively simple case.

You don't need to declare variables. You need each variable in each function.
In your case case z1 = x + y.
You can do this:
def add(x, y):
   return x + y

It is better to use Match-Case instead of if-else.
Here is code:
print("----------Simple Python Calculator----------\n")

def add(x, y):
   return x + y

def subtract(x, y):
   return x - y

def multiply(x, y):
   return x * y

def divide(x, y):
   return x / y

print("Select operation.\n")
print("1.Add")
print("2.Subtract")
print("3.Multiply")
print("4.Divide")

choice = input("\nEnter choice (1/2/3/4):")

num1 = int(input("\nEnter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: ")) 

match choice:
   case '1':
      print(num1,"+",num2,"=", add(num1,num2))
   case '2':
      print(num1,"-",num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2))
   case '3':
      print(num1,"*",num2,"=", multiply(num1,num2))
   case '4':
      print(num1,"/",num2,"=", divide(num1,num2))
   case _:
      print(r"Invalid input")  

Output:
Select operation.

1.Add
2.Subtract
3.Multiply
4.Divide

Enter choice (1/2/3/4):4

Enter first number: 64
Enter second number: 8
64 / 8 = 8.0


Because code is executed in order. In your code you asked for 3 inputs in a roll then did the calculation then displayed the output/message, so it will take 3 inputs then do the calculations then display the output depending on the first input. If you want the message to be display right after the first input, you need to move the code that output the message above the other two inputs.
ip1 = int(input("Enter your choice :"))
if ip1 == 1:
    x = int(input("enter 1st number :"))
    y = int(input("enter 2nd number :"))
    opt1 =("addition of {} and {} is {}")
    print(opt1.format(x, y, x + y))
elif ip1 == 2:
    x = int(input("enter 1st number :"))
    y = int(input("enter 2nd number :"))
    opt1 =("subtraction of {} and {} is {}")
    print(opt1.format(x, y, x - y))
elif ip1 == 3:
    x = int(input("enter 1st number :"))
    y = int(input("enter 2nd number :"))
    opt1 =("multiplication of {} and {} is {}")
    print(opt1.format(x, y, x * y))
elif ip1 == 4:
    x = int(input("enter 1st number :"))
    y = int(input("enter 2nd number :"))
    opt1 =("division of {} and {} is {}")
    print(opt1.format(x, y, x / y))
else:
    print("invalid parameter")


well, thanks but can you demonstrate this via an examples, actually i don't get what you said above

I just added code sample. If you want to do it your way, this is how it should be. Others' answers are better IMO.

print("[1]ADD")
print("[2]Subtract")
print("[3]Multiply")
print("[4]Divide")

ip1 = int(input("Enter your choice: "))

if ip1 in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    x = int(input("Enter 1st number: "))
    y = int(input("Enter 2nd number: "))
else:
    print("Invalid parameter")
    exit()

z1 = x + y
z2 = x - y
z3 = x * y
z4 = x / y

if ip1 == 1:
    print("Addition of {} and {} is {}".format(x, y, z1))
elif ip1 == 2:
    print("Subtraction of {} and {} is {}".format(x, y, z2))
elif ip1 == 3:
    print("Multiplication of {} and {} is {}".format(x, y, z3))
elif ip1 == 4:
    print("Division of {} and {} is {}".format(x, y, z4))


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
